# In python, how can I search a specific column for a specific value in a txt file then return the specific value's row?

Tags: python, python-2.7

First of all, I have recently started studying python. So I am a beginner.

```
1111  1  3  
1112  1  2  
1113  2  3  
1114  1  7  
1115  7  2
```

Assume I have these values in the text file. As in the title, I want to search a specific column for a specific value in the txt file then return the specific value's row except for the searched "value".

Example:

Search the first column for `1113` value.
Then return `2 3` as:

```
x = 2
y = 3
```

Comment: Is it your intention that the input data file has 2 spaces as the delimiter between values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('1113'):
            line = line.split()
            x = int(line[1])
            y = int(line[2])
```

as `'file.txt'` put your file name and as `'1113'` put the value you are looking for. good luck

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
import sys
with open( filename, "r" ) as f:
    for line in f:
        parts = line.split(" ")
        if parts[0] == "1113":
            print("x={0} y={1}".format( parts[1], parts[2] ))
            sys.exit(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReaderv) module which will do all the dirty work for you:

```
import csv

def find(filename, number):
    with open(filename) as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file,
                                fieldnames=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'],
                                delimiter=' ')
        for line in reader:
            if line['col1'] == str(number):
                return (line['col2'], line['col3'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    (x, y) = find('data.txt', 1113) or (None, None)
    print(x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer:

```
search_text = '1113'
with open(FileName) as f:
    for i in f:
        if i.strip() != '':
            for j in i.strip().split():
                if j[0] == search_text:
                    x = int(i[1])
                    y = int(i[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to search for any value on any column.

```
import csv


def find(reader, col, val):
    for row in reader:
        if row[col] == val:
            return row
    raise ValueError('Value {} not found in row {}'.format(val, col))


def findexcept(reader, col, val):
    r = find(reader, col, val)
    r.pop(col)
    return r

with open('searchdata.txt') as f:
    lines = (line.strip() for line in f)
    c = csv.reader(lines, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)

    try:
        x = findexcept(c, 0, '1114')
        print(x)
    except ValueError as ve:
        print('Error: {}'.format(ve))
```